# Upload file from url to AWS in laravel

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I know how to upload file from local storage to aws using laravel. But I want to upload file directly from external url to aws without downloading.

Any suggestion, how can I achieve this.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you @JayBlanchard but I am unable to find any link which is elaborating this and it is also not mentioned in the doc of laravel. Can you share link of some resources

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally solved this using [Intervention Image Library](http://image.intervention.io).

```
use Image;
use Storage;


$image = Image::make('url');
$image->encode('jpg');
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$filePath = '/profilePhotos/'.$time();
$s3->put($filePath, $image->__toString(), 'public');
```

Installation instructions for Image library can be found [here](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) in the "Integration in Laravel" section.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is dependent on another library. You can do it without the Intervention Image Library. Here is how you can do it-

```
$url = 'https://remote.site/photo/name.jpg'
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$name = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
Storage::put($name, $contents);
```